How to create a dash table that is editable and can be updated with callbacks?
I am working on a multipage webapp using Dash.
My goal would be to be able to catch user edits in the table and save it back
into the dataset and also let them filter it with the radio buttons.
I can make both of these work, but not together.
Helper function:
def setTable_data(df,id='table'):
        return dash_table.DataTable(
        id=id,
        columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in df.columns],
        data=df.to_dict('records'),
        fixed_columns={'headers': True, 'data': 1},
        editable = False,
        tooltip_header={i: i for i in df_def_list.columns},
        tooltip_delay=0,
        row_selectable= False,
        tooltip_duration=None,
        css=[{'selector': '.export',
        'rule': 'position:absolute;left:15px;bottom:-30px;color: #fff;background-         color: #17a2b8;border-color: #17a2b8;display: inline-block;font-weight: 400;text-align: center;white-space: nowrap;vertical-align: middle;transition: color .15s ease-in-out,background-color .15s ease-in-out,border-color .15s ease-in-out,box-shadow .15s ease-in-out;'}],
        style_cell={'minWidth': 110, 'maxWidth': 205,'textAlign': 'center'},
        export_format='csv',
        export_headers='display',
        fixed_rows={'headers': True},
        style_table={'height': '550px', 'overflowY': 'auto','minWidth': '100%'},
        style_data={'textOverflow': 'hidden'},
        style_header={'backgroundColor': '#5A5A5A',
                      'color': 'white',
                      'fontWeight': 'bold'})

This is the layout of the page in question:
dbc.RadioItems(
    options=[
    {"label": "Current Month", "value": 1},
    {"label": "Every Month", "value": 2},
    ],
    value=2,
    id="radioitems_layout_1",
    inline=True, persistence=True
    ),
html.Div(id="table_div",
    children=[
setTable_data(df,id='Monthly_Table')
])

This is the callback simplified:
@app.callback(
    Output('table_div', 'children'),
    Input('radioitems_layout_1', 'value'),
    State('Monthly_Table', 'data')
)
def display_and_edit_table(radio,n,save_clicks,data_current):
    data_a = dataiku.Dataset('a')
    df_a = data_a.get_dataframe()
    data_b = dataiku.Dataset('b')
    df_b = data_b.get_dataframe()
    if radio == 1:
        return setTable_data(df_a)
    elif radio == 2:
        return setTable_data(df_b)
#some edit and save functionality

As I understand I need an id for the dash table to make the editing work, but if I use this same id as the output of my callback then the layout doesn't update.
If I give an id to the container div and try to update it then upon use the radio buttons give a grey outline and are not responsive.
